# change mfrc522 module SPI to I2C

Tags: gpio, i2c, spi, rfid, modules

I'm working on a project where I need to use touchscreen and RC522 senzor on same Raspberry Pi, now I need to change senzor from SPI to I2C in order to do that I need to  change mfrc522 module which is programed for SPI to I2C. Anyone knows how to do that?

I installed modul as its shown on this page: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/

Comment: depends on the RC522 module you have - most I've seen breakout only the SPI pins - while I2C is possible, it's messy https://forum.arduino.cc/t/rc522-rfid-rc522-switching-spi-to-uart-interface-or-i2c-possible/425741/13 - of course, a Raspberry pi could have 1, 2, 3 or 6 (I think I've accounted for all possibilities) depending on the model Pi you have - and each SPI has at least 2 hardware CE pins

Comment: Of course, if your RC522 module doesn't breakout the i2c pins, then buy one that does

Comment: Your might find the following SPI/I2C RFID reader demo programs helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165652/how-can-rpi-read-a-pn532-nfc-module

Comment: So, is there a way to just use different code? Lets say I already have RC522 connected to I2C, is there a way to just reprogram modul for SPI to work on I2C? @JaromandaX I am completly new to Raspberry PI so i dont know a lot about pins, outputs...

Comment: Ah, I2C and SPI have different pins, so you need to change the hardware wiring. You CANNOT just use software to do that.

Comment: @tlfong01 Yes, I already know how to change wiring and how to enable I2C on Raspberry PI, but now I need to change software in order for it to work.

Comment: Well, my demo shows how to do SPI and I2C.

Comment: Or you can find an Arduino MFRC522 I2C (C++) Library - semaf
https://github.com/semaf/MFRC522_I2C_Library

MFRC522 I2C (C++) Library - arozcan
https://github.com/arozcan/MFRC522-I2C-Library

Comment: @tlfong01 sorry, but I get lost in that demo, do I just import those librarys like I did here: https://imgur.com/a/STZTJRA ?, will Arduino version work on Raspberry Pi? Is there a problem couse I use Pyhton and library is written in C++? Sorry for asking so much...

Comment: Ah, the library I used for testing both SPI and I2C is called libnfc 1.7, for PN532 module. It is different from your Simple MFRC522 python SPI library, which cannot do I2C. BTW, do you need to switch to I2C, because your display uses SPI can crashes with MFRC522 SPI? Perhaps you can find a SPI display or I2C display which does not crash with RFID.

Comment: @tlfong01 well, i think, if I would buy other screen, I would just buy one who doesn not need GPIO pins at all....Well my Screen needs SPI, so i am changeing RC522 sensor to I2C, guy who gave me project bought this components for me, and said, I JUST need to switch senzor to I2C and reprogram it. Now i am stuck, couse i tought I will just like for SPI type IMPORT FROM and thats it, but it seems like that does not exist for I2C

Comment: Ah, I mentioned the display problem, because these couple of years I did answer quite a few questions on WS displays which ridiculously exclusively use SPI and impossible to change.  So my suggestion is to swap a SPI/I2C friendly display instead of swapping RFID SPI ot I2C which might cause newer and bigger problems. In other words, the comment "I JUST need to switch sensor to I2C and reprogram it" is a big joke. :) Good luck and cheers.

Comment: haha thats why i typed just in caps, this is killing me, I finished project and than he wants touchscreen, I already needed to format SD card with all data on it like 3 times... So best way out is to buy other Touchscreen?  @tlfong01

Comment: Well, it is hard to say what is the "BEST" way out, because there are too many things to consider. As you say, you are stuck. But if it is your inlaw's project, then all ways are best. Best of luck. Cheers.